# Android LogCat displaying messages multiple times instead of once

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm working on a project which is connecting to web server and gets data stream from it. For testing purposes I'm showing all the data in `LogCat` so I can be sure that everything is right.

I'm testing my application in 2 devices:

- HTC EVO 3D
- HTC DESIRE.

At one point I noticed something strange: when I'm testing on `EVO 3D` I saw that I'm getting all packets of data stream twice, which is really strange because server cannot send me one packet two times. I thought it's because of `EVO's` dual core processor.

But after that I noticed the same problem with `HTC Desire` and in `emulator` too. On emulator I'm getting all packets even three times.

The problem is that it's not always happening. I looked closer at that problem and I saw that `LogCat` is showing all running processes on my devices and emulator twice or more and actually I started thinking that it's `LogCat` bug and have nothing to do with my application.

So my question: is anybody else getting the same strange behaviour of LogCat? Is it an SDK bug, or the problem is in my application code?

(I just tried with other applications, and the result is the same).

Comment: im getting this error too. it only seems to affect my devices running gingerbread 2.3.5 though. my jellybean device doesnt suffer from this.

i find it hard to believe nobody has come up with a solution to this yet. ive searched many pages via google, and cant find an  explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noticed it's probably some kind of `LogCat` bug, because I debug my code maybe 50 times and find that there is nothing which can reproduce that problem. And I did check the request to the server which I am sending. It was only one request, not more. So that's why I started of thinking that it's probably an `LogCat` bug.

Comment: So how do you bypass the problem or solve it eventually?