# Android LogCat displaying messages multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I am printing logging from logcat to a text file on my (not virtual) android device(android 4.2.2). The app runs 24/7. The problem is that everything is logged multiple times.

Logcat:

```
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 I/EFLog   ( 8303): start new thread: Thread[Thread-20688,5,main]
09-22 15:15:06.924 F/test    ( 8303):  token : xxxxxxxx
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: 10:00:00:26:39:f0, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
09-22 15:15:06.944 I/EFLog   ( 8303): connection available
```

Not everything is displayed multiple times.

There are 2 similair questions that don't answer my question because they are both about virtual machines.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771616/logcat-showing-information-3-times-on-avd) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594398/android-logcat-displaying-messages-multiple-times-instead-of-once)